# ¿Por que Where y orWhere tienen conflictos?

Tags: laravel

Estoy realizado una búsqueda con `eloquent` laravel, pero me surgió un problema al momento de tener 2 `where` y un `orWhere`, ya que en mi base de datos trabajamos por `state [0, 1]` para ver si un registro ha sido de baja.

Pero al momento de buscar un usuario surge lo siguiente:

```
$users = User::where('code', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->search.'%')
                  ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->search.'%')
                  ->where('state', 1)
                  ->get();
```

Pongo al final el where para que solo me muestre los usuarios que no han sido dados de baja, pero al buscar aún me siguen mostrando.

```
return $users;

[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "code": "USR-001",
    "name": "Jhon Smith",
    "state": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "code": "USR-002",
    "name": "Carlos Smith",
    "state": 1
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que tienes que usar es una `funcion` para poder controlar el `where` y el `orWhere`.

Prueba esto:

```
$search = $request->search;
$users = User::where('state', 1)->where(function($query) use ($search){
                  $query->where('code', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')
                  ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%');
})->get();
```